# What is the right way to query Polkadot js for a Substrate storage key?

Tags: node.js, rpc, substrate, polkadot-js

I am trying to pull a large array from Substrate storage, and when querying via node.js I get "Unable to decode Vec on index 0 Source is too large".

So switching to curl and the JSON RPC interface, I wanted to check I could generate hashes correctly in node.js and then use them to query via RPC directly. Trying

```
const { xxhashAsHex, blake2AsHex } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { stringToU8a } = require('@polkadot/util');
...
console.log(xxhashAsHex(stringToU8a("Sudo key"), 128));
```

(trying to follow [Shawn's RPC page](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/)), I get:

```
0x845f1811116060262abe72f228571eca
```

But Shawn lists the answer as:

```
0x50a63a871aced22e88ee6466fe5aa5d9
```

Using Shawn's value in a json RPC call gives the expected result:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 
  '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"state_getStorage",
    "params":["0x50a63a871aced22e88ee6466fe5aa5d9"]}'
    http://127.0.0.1:9933/ 
> {"jsonrpc":"2.0",
 "result":"0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d",
  "id":1}
```

If I query `sudo.key` directly, I do get the expected answer:

```
console.log((await api.query.sudo.key()).toHex());
> 0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
```

So what gives?

Comment: Hi Phil H, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 4):

This was solved in chat by Jaco.

What I needed was to query `xxhashAsHex(stringToU8a("Sudo Key"), 128)` (note the capital K).